# User lookup by user id failed in AAD

Tags: c#, azure, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-teams

I'm trying to create MS Teams Meeting using Microsoft.Graph.Beta SDK in .NET core application. I'm using the following code to create the meeting.

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var clientId = "<Enter you Client ID here>";
            var tenantId = "<Enter your tenand ID here>";
            var clientSecret = "<Enter your client secret here>";
            var scopes = new string[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };

            ///The client credential flow enables service applications to run without user interaction. 
            ///Access is based on the identity of the application.
            IConfidentialClientApplication confidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
            .Create(clientId)
            .WithTenantId(tenantId)
            .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
            .Build();

            ClientCredentialProvider authProvider = new ClientCredentialProvider(confidentialClientApplication);



            var onlinemeeting = CreateTeamsMeeting(authProvider).GetAwaiter().GetResult();


            Console.ReadLine();
        }


        public static async Task<OnlineMeeting> CreateTeamsMeeting(IAuthenticationProvider authProvider)
        {
            GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);

            var onlineMeeting = new OnlineMeeting
            {
                StartDateTime = DateTimeOffset.Parse("2020-11-12T21:30:34.2444915+00:00"),
                EndDateTime = DateTimeOffset.Parse("2020-11-12T22:00:34.2464912+00:00"),
                Subject = "User Token Meeting",
            };

            return await graphClient.Me.OnlineMeetings
                .Request()
                .AddAsync(onlineMeeting);
        }
```

However, upon running the above code, I receive the following error.

> Server error: **User lookup by user id failed in AAD**. Client exception:
> Processing of the HTTP request resulted in an exception. Please see
> the HTTP response returned by the 'Response' property of this
> exception for details.
>
> Inner error:  AdditionalData:     date: 2020-11-09T12:19:53   request-id:
> 02cd2168-d0d8-437a-9eee-117f1924a387  client-request-id:
> 02cd2168-d0d8-437a-9eee-117f1924a387 ClientRequestId:
> 02cd2168-d0d8-437a-9eee-117f1924a387

[image]

How do we fix this error??

Comment: You are using client credential flow based on [Client credentials provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=CS#ClientCredentialsProvider). So you should use `graphClient.Users["{user id/upn}"].OnlineMeetings.Request().AddAsync(onlineMeeting)` rather than `graphClient.Me.OnlineMeetings.Request().AddAsync(onlineMeeting)`.

Comment: And if you want to implement **Get the token as a user**, you should choose [Authorization code provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=CS#AuthCodeProvider) or [Username/password provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=CS#UsernamePasswordProvider). Then you could keep using `graphClient.Me.OnlineMeetings.Request().AddAsync(onlineMeeting)`.

Comment: Hi Thanks @AllenWu for sharing the answer. This was helpful. I've tried your approach. But this following error come. 'Application does not have permission to Create online meeting on behalf of this user.' 

Would appreciate if you could share your thoughts on it. thank you.

Comment: Have added an answer. If any of the answers is helpful, you can mark it as accepted. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@juusnas's answer is correct. I just organize my comments here for easy reference.

You are using client credential flow based on [Client credentials provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=CS#ClientCredentialsProvider). So you should use `graphClient.Users["{user id/upn}"].OnlineMeetings.Request().AddAsync(onlineMeeting)` rather than `graphClient.Me.OnlineMeetings.Request().AddAsync(onlineMeeting)`.

And if you want to implement **Get the token as a user**, you should choose [Authorization code provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=CS#AuthCodeProvider) or [Username/password provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=CS#UsernamePasswordProvider). Then you could keep using `graphClient.Me.OnlineMeetings.Request().AddAsync(onlineMeeting)`.

For permission error, you need to add Application permission (not delegated permission) `OnlineMeetings.ReadWrite.All` into your App registration.

[image]

And based on the **Important** tip [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-onlinemeetings?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http#permissions), you also must [create an application access policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/cloud-communication-online-meeting-application-access-policy) to allow applications to access online meetings on behalf of a user.

Answer (score 1):

You have acquired a token as the application, with client credentials flow.
This does not make sense:

```
graphClient.Me.
```

Who is "me"?
Normally that is the user on behalf of who the app is making the API call.
But because you acquired the token as the app, there isn't a user.

You need to either:

1. Get the token as a user (don't use client credentials)
2. Use an API that is not dependent on user identity (not sure if Teams has those)

Comment: Hi @juunas thanks for sharing the answer. Though I'm new to MS Graph SDK, what you said made sense. I need more information on how do I get the token as a user and how do I execute the command. Since graphClient.Me.isn't the approach I should follow, do we have any code snippet that I can look into maybe? Thank you